# Uncaught TypeError: e is not a function at MicrosoftTeams.min.js:1

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to get the access token in team tab to make a call to the graph api
using the following repo
[teams tab aad msal2](https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/main/samples/tab-aad-msal2)

error description
[image: error description]

Comment: Which MS Teams version are you using? Could you please try to upgrade Microsoft Teams version and check if it works.

Comment: you mean teams SDK?

Comment: Have make any changes in the sample or running it directly and getting error?

Comment: Made changes with respect to client Id, tenant I'd and redirect url

Comment: @UmamaheshwariG, We are able to repro the issue. Although its not impacting any functionality, but whenever the tab loads its showing this error in console.

Comment: @Umamaheshwari G, Is it a blocker for you?